# Efficient structure for storing/handling lots of datasets

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to develop a piece of software which will probably store hundred of thousands or even millions of datasets with 3 to 5 datasets to look up per ID.

Is there any way to build something like this efficient, fast and scalable in regards of "lookup time" using PHP and MySQL?

I thought about trees for easier lookup, but I´m not sure this will really work, as my IDs won´t be numeric but most probably strings which have no relation at all.

Think of the datasets as some kind of thesaurus where one input might have several other datasets linked.

`E9NQin0usg < == > zHVauTqpzF
                   Th0a647ALJ
                   pEwIW0MrNX
                   vEfdqNMqkW
                   8t5LfEm1Ea`

Normally I would build something like this with PHP/MySQL:

`table_in
ID | value
1  | E9NQin0usg`

**table_out**
ID | type | value
1  | alt1 | zHVauTqpzF
2  | alt2 | Th0a647ALJ
3  | alt4 | pEwIW0MrNX
4  | alt5 | vEfdqNMqkW

**table_in_out**
ID_IN | ID_OUT
1     | 1
1     | 2
1     | 3
1     | 4

And then query the *_in_out* table for matching pairs and do more lookup in the *_out* table to get information about the type of the alternative.

I think this might be inefficient as my *_in_out* table will grow quite a lot, as each new dataset on the *_in* table will create up to 5 datasets in the *_out* and obviously the *_in_out* table.

So I wonder if there is a way to build this faster and more efficient.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable.  What does each of these data sets look like?

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for commenting. You are right, there was too little information. I added an example and the approach I would normally choose. I hope this helps, otherwise let me know.

Comment: Have you looked into creating indexes on these string values? You may be surprised on the lookup boost you get, but be warned, you may have to sacrifice speed of data entry and changing if you take it too far.

Comment: Hey @JeffO, I will have a look into that, sounds like this could help.